# Android background service: CPU and network usage doubts

Tags: android, networking, service, cpu-usage

I am developing a custom chat application.

Sent messages are stored on my server using a simple POST.

A service that runs in background is responsible to check using another POST every **5 seconds**  if there are new messages for the current user and send a notification to the him/her.

I am a bit worried about network and CPU usages because i am aware that internet connection is used all the day.

*I used that approach because i need to manipulate some data on my server code before delivery a notification to receiver.*

*An example is that i have some users assigned as admin. The users username is their email. When a message is sent from one of the admins i overwrite their username (so their email) with the application name before delivery the notification to the receiver.*

Is this the best approach to create a custom chat application?

Comment: You are rewriting their email with username everytime they send some message? Why do you need that to be made on server side, not app side?

Comment: Yes i do it. Simply because someone can decompile it and change this behavior. Magically being able to send messages to all the community...

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly why you used this use case, but really simple solution provides Firebase.

You can read something about that [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397). Basically you have to:

1. Create some layouts
2. Add listener on "send message" click, that will add message to firebase realtime database
3. Create `FirebaseListAdapter`, who will display messages to user

From [database docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

> all of your clients share one Realtime Database instance and
>   automatically receive updates with the newest data.

From my understading you dont have to check every 5 seconds if there is some message waiting. Firebase handles it for you.

Comment: Basically i have a couple of users that are admins. When they send a chat message i overwrite in my server php code their details using an hardcoded name. Using firebase i can't have a control of such data. Do you have any idea to suggest me?